# Is there a log4j appender for Moogsoft?

Tags: log4j, alert

Our current approach is to:

1. Send all events to Splunk (through [Splunk's own log4j-appender](https://github.com/splunk/splunk-library-javalogging)).
2. Define Splunk alerts, which trigger Moogsoft.

Obviously, this increases the latency and relies on Splunk more than necessary. Which makes me wonder, if someone has already developed a Moogsoft-appender for log4j.

A simple search hasn't brought anything up -- hence this question.

Answer (score 1):

i haven't done this, but log4j has a SocketAppender
https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j/log4j-socketappender-and-socket-server-example/

that might fit with Moogsofts SocketLam
https://docs.moogsoft.com/en/configure-the-socket-lam.html

Alternatively:
https://github.com/logstash/log4j-jsonevent-layout
gives json layout to log4j which then could be received with a REST Lam

Comment: I asked MoogSoft about a LAM to handle `SocketAppender`-submitted events. Logstash's layout seems to be for log4j*2* -- I have log4j-1.2...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anyone that has put together an actual appender, but I don't think you'd need one.  An [HTTP appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#HttpAppender) with a [JSON layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout) sending to a [Moogsoft REST adapter](https://docs.moogsoft.com/en/rest-lam.html) should be able to do the job, and might be a lot easier to set up than handling raw bytes off a socket.

I haven't done it so I'm not sure how much work it would be to set up.  I suspect there's some work involved on either the log4j side to get the layout to look like Moogsoft wants it, or on the Moogsoft side to normalize what it gets sent.

Comment: Thanks, that might be sufficient for users of log4j-2.x. However, we have a number of vendor-provided applications still using log4j-1.2, for which there are no fancy appenders already available "out of the box". One would have to implement and then _maintain_ one's own... Accepting events over the `SocketAppender` would've been the smartest thing for Moogsoft to do...